# Visual basic closing a file

Tags: file, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual basic 2012, and I'm experimenting with manipulating .txt files. I've managed to make a button to create them, but the button I made to delete them always runs into and error, claiming the file is still in use. I've tried to write code to close the file, but no success. The closest I've gotten was when I tried

```
    FileStream.Close("C:\Testfile")
```

But I get an error saying that It needs to be linked to an object. I don't have the faintest idea what it mean by object, and I don't have any other ideas
Can someone tell me what I need to do to fix this, or alternatively, another solution

Comment: Please share the code in which you create/open the file as well

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that the code you have for [creating the file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa735748%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), closes that file as well after the job is done:

```
Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\Testfile")
' write to the file here, like:
sw.Write("...")
' ...etc, and at the end of the job, close the file:
sw.Close()
```

To actually [delete a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) from the file system, use:

```
 File.Delete("C:\Testfile")
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem that you are having could be because the file is still open when you are trying to delete it.

Add your file manipulation code inside a `Using` block as explained in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). By using this technique you will not have to remember to close files yourself as it will happen automatically once you have left the `Using` block.

```
Dim filePath As String = "hello.txt"

Using openedFile As FileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
    'File is OPEN
    Dim bytes() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World")
    openedFile.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
End Using

'File is CLOSED and can be deleted
File.Delete(filePath)
```

You can also use this technique for any other objects that implement `IDisposable` such as `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.